# String concatenation in awk

Tags: awk, concatenation

Consider the following text file (test.txt) :

```
1 1 1
7 7 6
```

and the awk script (test.awk)

```
{
    print "$0 : ", $0
    lines=(lines $0)
    print "lines : ", lines
}
```

Then running:

```
awk -f test.awk test.txt
```

gives output

```
$0 :  1 1 1
lines :  1 1 1
$0 :  7 7 6
7 7 6 :  1 1 1
```

while the expected output should (as far as I can see) have been:

```
$0 :  1 1 1
lines :  1 1 1
$0 :  7 7 6
lines : 1 1 17 7 6
```

what am I missing here?

(I am using GNU Awk 3.1.8 on Ubuntu 12.04)

Comment: the above works as expected for me on Arch Linux.  Change the `lines=(lines $0)` line in your test.awk file to `lines=(lines $0 " ")` to add a space between the lines, otherwise the end result, when working, is `lines : 1 1 17 7 6`

Comment: I'm using awk version `4.1.0`, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, for the comments.. Then, since it works for you, it must be something wrong with my confiugration I guess?

Comment: You're welcome; I dunno, I guess... I don't think that I have `awk` configured at all.  You could try specifying the delimiter as `\n` using `-F "\n"`, but I think that your best bet would be to check for an update and then if that still doesn't help, then check your configuration.

Comment: If you do have a custom configuration of `awk`, please add it to your post.

Comment: I checked more: Running `xxd -p test.txt` gives output `31203120310d0a37203720360d0a`.. It seems that carriage returns (hexadecimal 0d) have entered the input text file..

Comment: Yup; that's the trouble...DOS format.  I was writing my answer as you discovered that.

Comment: At first, I had considered that DOS line-endings might have been the problem, but I dismissed the possibility since he said he was running Linux.  :P

Comment: Actually the text file was produced by a windows program.. and then imported to linux.. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got DOS line endings in `test.txt` (CRLF, or `\r\n` at the end of each line).

Output with Unix line endings:

```
$0 :  1 1 1
lines :  1 1 1
$0 :  7 7 6
lines :  1 1 17 7 6
```

Output with DOS line endings:

```
$0 :  1 1 1
lines :  1 1 1
$0 :  7 7 6
7 7 6 :  1 1 1
```

Output with DOS line endings formatted with a hex-dump program:

```
0x0000: 24 30 20 3A 20 20 31 20 31 20 31 0D 0A 6C 69 6E   $0 :  1 1 1..lin
0x0010: 65 73 20 3A 20 20 31 20 31 20 31 0D 0A 24 30 20   es :  1 1 1..$0 
0x0020: 3A 20 20 37 20 37 20 36 0D 0A 6C 69 6E 65 73 20   :  7 7 6..lines 
0x0030: 3A 20 20 31 20 31 20 31 0D 37 20 37 20 36 0D 0A   :  1 1 1.7 7 6..
0x0040:
```

The `0D` codes are the CR line endings.

Comment: Yes (the `sub("\r","")` would work), or use Unix files on Unix systems, if necessary using FTP in text mode to transfer files, or using `dos2unix` or equivalent to convert files from DOS to Unix.